# Google Maps aren't showing

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const GMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GMap> createState() => _GMapState();
}

class _GMapState extends State<GMap> {
  final Set  <Marker> _marker = HashSet<Marker>();
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    _mapController = controller;
    setState(() {
      _marker.add(Marker(
        markerId:MarkerId("0"),
        position: LatLng(2.2214, 102.4531),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(

        )
      ));
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Map'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[ GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(2.2214, 102.4531),
            zoom: 12,
      ),
        markers: _marker,
      ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 32),
        child: const Text("Test"),
        )
    ]
    )
    );
  }
}
```

So here's  the coding on my googlemap.dart, my google maps aren't showing for somehow it just show blank white screen after I run the code, I'm not sure what was the problem and if anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it

Comment: Could you please share the android AndroidManifest file here

Comment: because i follow the guide from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0NfbhF2A3g , I did the same as he did af the min 4, but he can show the widget while mine just show white screen

Comment: Please add API in the AndroidManifest file and info.pilist file and rebuild app and check

Answer (score -1):

Please set API Key. error with your api key not coding.

Comment: because i follow the guide from youtube youtube.com/watch?v=N0NfbhF2A3g , I did the same as he did af the min 4, but he can show the widget while mine just show white screen